# Appending Two Mp3 files in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-mediaplayer, android-file

How can i append two audio files in android. I tried this but it does not work. pls  give me a soln.I need to concatenate the files from sdcard  that ts A.mp3 and B.mp3 .When i merge concatenate  method calls i want both of them as a single file in sdcard that is C.mp3........

```
File original= new File("/mnt/sdcard/A.mp3");
 File temp=new File("/mnt/sdcard/B.mp3");
        Log.i("...............",""+path);


        try {
            File outFile= new File("/mnt/sdcard/C.mp3 ");

            DataOutputStream out=new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile)));





        //  FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(outFile);

            //OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(original,true);


            int m,n;
            m=(int) temp.length();
            n=(int) original.length();

             byte[] buf1 = new byte[m];
             byte[] buf2 = new byte[n];

             byte[] outBytes = new byte[m+n];


             DataInputStream dis1=new DataInputStream(  new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(original)));
             DataInputStream dis2=new DataInputStream(  new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(temp)));



             dis1.read(buf1, 0, m);
             dis1.close();

             dis2.readFully(buf2, 0, n);
             dis2.close();


             out.write(buf1);
             out.write(buf2);
            out.flush();


                //in.close();
                out.close();
                System.out.println("File copied.");


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I need to combine The File A.mp3,B.mp3 to C.mp3....

Comment: mp3 format is copyrighted,you cant do same if you dont have valid lecence

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of knowbody, you can refer to the mp3 file format specification for more information [HERE](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html) and [HERE](http://www.multiweb.cz/twoinches/mp3inside.htm).

There are a lot of things you should consider when stitching two mp3 files. The least to say is that they need to be encoded by the same program, with the same settings or if we're speaking about voice, to be taken from the same microphone, set with the same settings etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;
public class TwoFiles
{
    public static void Main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fistream1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Temp\\1.mp3");
        FileInputStream fistream2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Temp\\2.mp3");
        SequenceInputStream sistream = new SequenceInputStream(fistream1, fistream2);
        FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Temp\\final.mp3");

    int temp;

    while( ( temp = sistream.read() ) != -1)
    {

        fostream.write(temp);  
    }
    fostream.close();
    sistream.close();
    fistream1.close();
    fistream2.close();
}
}
```

I hope is clear

Comment: I tried your code and got size of new file as total of two files but when i play that combined new file it plays only first one... can you help me with this