# Mp3 file is not playing after converting from byte[] android

Tags: android, base64, mp3, decode, encode

I just convert a mp3 file to byte code and reconvert that byte code to mp3 and saved to sdcard, all the process are going successfully but problem is that the saved mp3 file is not playing on device mp3 player it showing unsupported format.

Is there any problem in my below code

```
  private void convertBytesToFile(byte[] bytearray) {


    byte[] bytes = bytearray;

    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);
  //  Utilities.log("~~~~~~~~ Encoded: ", encoded);

    byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(encoded, 0);
    //Utilities.log("~~~~~~~~ Decoded: ", Arrays.toString(decoded));

    try
    {
        File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hello-2.mp3");
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file2, true);

        os.write(decoded);
        os.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Somthing wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

or anything am I missing from.
Please help friends.

Comment: Why do you encode and decode in `Base64`? How `Base64` is anyhow related to `mp3` encoding?

Comment: Yeah I think my process is wrong.Is there any another way ?  Actually I just want to join two mp3 file and make another mp3 file that's why I just try to encode and decode using Base64. Any other way to make this ? Plz help.

Comment: You could check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381585/concatenate-mp3-files-in-java)

Comment: consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088806/appending-two-mp3-files-in-android) too

Comment: Let me check.. Thank you.. :D

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Thank you so much, But that was not my answer, Any example regarding joining two mp3 files through coding or any library ? Please help.

Comment: Well, If I were you I would rather do it with FFmpeg https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: Hi as you are refer I am trying to use FFmpeg on my android studio. Now after compiling in terminal its giving me following errors..arm-linux-
If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem. what to do now

Comment: It showing C compiler test failed. I am install gcc and g++ and my ndk path is NDK=D:/Users/BIP042.BIPADBBSR/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle     whats the wrong any idea.. Please help..

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)?

Comment: It is not possible to just join two mp3 files. The beginning of the second file will habe meta-data attached that is not allowed to be in the middle of your newly generated file. Is your example a minimal test, without joining two files?

Comment: Yeah its a minimal test..

Comment: you have to do signal processing , convert both files to same frequency rate and channel , and then combine these files , you can find more information about signal processing in google

Comment: Thanks let me check about signal processing.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why did you convert that mp3 to Base64? If you want to save to sd card do below code

```
private void convertBytesToFile(byte[] bytearray) {

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hello-2.mp3");
    fos.write(byteArray);
    fos.close()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For playing MP3 ( In your scenario )

```
private void playMp3(byte[] mp3SoundByteArray) {
        try {
            // create temp file that will hold byte array
            File tempMp3 = File.createTempFile("fmtemp", "mp3", getCacheDir());
            tempMp3.deleteOnExit();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempMp3);
            fos.write(mp3SoundByteArray);
            fos.close();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempMp3);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK doesn't have mp3 encoder. If you want to save byte[] to .mp3 file,Use native library as below.

https://github.com/naman14/TAndroidLame
https://github.com/yhirano/SimpleLameLibForAndroid

Answer (score 0):

As [Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3612433/jonas-k%C3%B6ritz) metioned, merging two mp3 files is not as easy as merging their bytes as the files contain meta-data. There is a solution though, you can use [FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android). You can either use the native build or a wrapper such as [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv). Here is sample of how to merge two Mp3 files using JavaCV

```
      FrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("input.mp3"); 
             grabber.start(); 

  FrameGrabber grabber2 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("input2.mp3"); 
             grabber2.start(); 

             FrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("output.mp3", 
    grabber.getAudioChannels()); 
             recorder.setSampleFormat(grabber.getSampleFormat()); 
             recorder.setSampleRate(grabber.getSampleRate()); 
             recorder.start(); 
             Frame frame; 
             while ((frame = grabber.grabFrame()) != null) { 
                 recorder.record(frame); 
             }
            while ((frame = grabber2.grabFrame()) != null) { 
                 recorder.record(frame); 
             } 
             recorder.stop(); 
             grabber.stop(); 
            grabber2.stop();
```

PS Im assuming that the sample rate for both files is the same

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioConverter

(Convert audio files inside your Android app easily. Supported formats: AAC, MP3, M4A, WMA, WAV and FLAC)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code may resolve your issue,

```
private void convertBytesToFile(byte[] bytearray) {
    try {

        File outputFile = File.createTempFile("MediaFile", "mp3", getCacheDir());
        outputFile.deleteOnExit();
        FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(outputmediafile);
        fileoutputstream.write(bytearray);
        fileoutputstream.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Play the media file in any media player.